# Odd Linked List Representation

Tags: c++, c, memory, linked-list

I am trying to find a way to store void pointers to blocks of memory via a linked list, and I came across this representation.

```
//Initalization

void * list;

//Add void pointer

void add_pointer(void * p) {
  *(void **)p = list;
  list = p;
}

//Remove pointer with address

void remove_pointer(void * p) {
  void ** iter;
  iter = &list;

  while ((*iter != NULL) && (*iter != p)) {
    iter = (void **)*iter;
  }

  if (*iter == p) {
    *iter = *(void **)p;
  }
}
```

How does this even work? Is the address of the next block stored in the previous block's data where the void pointer is pointing to? Assume the list is initialized to NULL.

Also, does this assume that the every void pointer's block has no data written in it? If anybody can shed any light on how this implementation works, that would be excellent, it just seems very esoteric that it can function as a linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It assumes the first field in the node is the slot for the link pointer, which is a `void *`. And `list` is a `void *` and it always points to the head of the linked list.

`add_pointer()` function adds a new node to the beginning of the list. The `void *p` argument points to the new node to be added. The function casts the `void *` p to a `void **` so that `*(void **)p` can hold a `void *` pointer. The function stores the previous head pointer in this location as

```
*(void **)p = list; // list is a void * to the first element
```

It then sets `list` to be the `void *` to the new first element, i.e, p.

Now the `remove_pointer()` function removes a node from the list, taking as argument a `void *` pointing to it. `iter` is used for iterating the list. It is initially assigned the address of `list` so that `*iter` will give the link pointer which is assumed to be the first field in the node always. The while loop updates `iter` to the next node in the list until it finds `p` (which is the node to be removed) in the link pointer field of the current node. At this point, it updates the link pointer filed of the current node to point to the link pointer field value of the node pointed to by p, which is done by the statement

```
*iter = *(void **)p; // *iter gives the link pointer filed of the current node
                     // p, is the node to be removed, *(void **)p gives the value in  
                     // the link pointer filed of p
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's more clear to me now. Would this implementation work regardless of the value pointed to by the void pointer, or would the value need to be zeroed before adding it to the list, so that its value can be used for a pointer to the next block?

Comment: @jab: `add_pointer()` doesn't care what was in the link - the first thing it does is overwrite the link 'field' with the pointer in `list`.

Answer (score 2):

It just makes the assumption that the very first field of the node is a slot for the link pointer.  It casts the node pointer to a `(void**)` so it can store a `void*` at that address.

And, of course, `list` is a hard-coded location for the pointer to the first node on the linked list.

Not the most flexible list design.